# Linking a field from one table to another table (not table field) in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This may not be possible but I'm trying to figure out a solution to link a field from one table to a separate table without having to map an id to a table name in my code.

I've attached a simple image of what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a PRODUCTTYPES table which has a productType field where I would like to enter an id that represents a TABLE (The schema's are different for every table I'm trying to link to). I have another field called productID that would then link to ID of that table. That part is easy to do but the issue is based on the productType in PRODUCTTYPES I need to know which table to query to link the productID to the tables ID.

Is this something that can only be done via code by putting the name of the table in the productType field? For example, instead of productID=2 it would be productID=Shoes

[image]

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do with this database? Do you want a table of products that have categories?

Comment: No I have that taken care of. I'm working on a custom eCommerce solution that has custom product types. I've simplified down the tables for sake of explanation but this is essentially where I'm hung up. Since each product type has a different schema I'm looking for the most elegant way to link them to a product type table.

Comment: make a producttypes table then have a foreign key product_type_id on products table. don't make each type a table. Same goes with the products. make a products table with id avoid making tables for each attribute

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm after. Each product type is a completely different schema needing completely different fields (other than ID). That is the reason for having different tables for each product type, because they store different data completely.

Comment: why are you making each type a different table? what is the reasoning for it? because it violates normalization rules and makes data retrieval impossible later

Comment: Well say each type has 15 different fields, and there's 3 different types, how else would you do it? Are you saying to have one table with all three of their fields in there? That would be a total of 45 fields in a table. I guess I'm thinking about this like objects, where each type is it's all object (tables) that have their own children (the rows) that are all product types and need to be classified as to what type of product they are in the PRODUCTTYPES table. Does that make sense?